# Why does my render show a metarig in the background despite me not even having a metarig?

Tags: rendering, rigging, eevee-render-engine, rigify

[image]

Here's a link to my blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tFKAUjFU1ch9TOtMTpS2OGNoR1VBtKxG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a metarig, it is just a "drawing" of a metarig. It is the grease pencil object called "Stroke" in the collections "Grease" > "Armor".

[image: grease pencil object]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was beginning to think a rigify ghost was haunting my project lmao

Comment: @BrandonBernal There is a simple way to track it down even when you cannot seem to find a way to select it in the viewport, might be tedious in larger scenes but anyway: disable top collections one by one to see when it disappears... then go further down the hierarchy until you find it. But it seems to me that it also creates an outline for the objects, so maybe you should not completely remove it but somehow "repair" it so that it only shows what you want?

Comment: I'll keep that strat in mind, thanks!